# ngx translate not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngx-translate

I have an ionic 3 project and I want to use ngx translate.
It works in the browser and the iOS simulator but not on a real device (tested on iPhone SE, iOS 11.1).

app.module.ts

```
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export function HttpLoaderFactory (http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    [...],
    imports: [
        [...]
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My files are here:

src/assets/i18n/DE.json

src/assets/i18n/EN.json

I translate it this way:

```
<ion-title translate>
    {{ 'LOGIN.HEADER' | translate }}
</ion-title>
```

Does someone know why it won't be translated on a device?

Comment: Are you using `WKWebView`?

Comment: @sebaferreras: I'm using the Ionic WebView. I think it is the WKWebView.

Comment: I tried to change it to the UIWebView by adding `<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />` to my config.xml, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please take a look at **[this comment](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/642#issuecomment-344266618)** and let me know if that fixes the issue. Btw you should keep `WkWebView` since `UiWebView` will be deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I got the error that `.map` does not exist on type `Observable<string>`. So, I couldn't really test it. I tried to rewrite it without success. Then I just wrote `return this.http.get(`./assets/i18n/EN.json`);` From this moment it worked and it also with my old implementation (+ I changed the language file name to lowercase (en.json, de.json) what I have tried already so many times before).
So, I don't really know why, but it seems to work now. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmmm that's strange... but glad to hear that you solved the issue :)

Comment: @chocolatecake, where did you write that? I mean `return this.http.get(./assets/i18n/EN.json);`. Maybe it would help me as well

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be the code line in part 3 of sebaferreras' comment. I cleared this code in my project cause the old way worked magically.
Maybe a total clear and rebuild could work as well?
If your problem occurs when you change the language, try to write `<ion-title translate>LOGIN.HEADER</ion-title>` without the line breaks.
(Just now, I've seen I used "translate" duplicate. One of these should be enough.)
Hope this helps!

Comment: try using https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix

Answer (score 1):

it might be a bit late, but for those who still experience this issue please do either of the following solutions:

- Update ngx-translate to the latest version by running `npm install @ngx-translate/core` & `npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader`
- or follow this solution for a CustomLoader from https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/642#issuecomment-344266618 by sebaferreras
- or follow the solution on this post [Ionic 3 Response with status: 0 for URL: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170019/ionic-3-response-with-status-0-for-url-null) by CodeChanger